# this.container.lookupFactory no longer works in ember@2.2.0

Tags: ember.js

Since updating to *ember@2.2.0*

```
const config = this.container.lookupFactory('config:environment');`
```

no longer works. I can't use:

```
import ENV from 'your-application-name/config/environment';
```

because I don't actually know what the application-name is as I am using this in an addon and also some blueprints.

What is the alternative?

Comment: Can't you use `import ENV from '../config/environment';`?

Comment: From a blueprint that would work (with the correct number of `../` for the pods structure).  I remember this not working in the addon namespace though because it does not have access to the consuming applications environment.js.

Comment: Ah, missed the addon part. Should have read slower.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer by @jax does not provide the solution. I found the [solution on EmberJS forums](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/best-practices-accessing-app-config-from-addon-code/7006/19):

```
Ember.getOwner(this).resolveRegistration('config:environment');
```

See http://emberjs.com/api/classes/RegistryProxyMixin.html#method_resolveRegistration

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution, it has been deprecated.

http://emberjs.com/deprecations/v2.x/#toc_injected-container-access

Comment: Indeed, though that should be starting from v2.3. But maybe you are using the beta or canary build, which are already preparing v2.3?

Comment: I am actually using the release.  It turned out to be liquid-fire breaking by app when upgrading to 2.2.0.  Everywhere I had a `{{liquid-outlet}}` the app would fail.  I must have seen the deprecation warning on the above and thought that it was the culprit.